# JavaFX: How do I set a Background Image in code?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have a control that must be highly customizable, and that means being able to use an image for the control background. To that end I need to know how I can, in code, set the CSS Style to point to the image specified by the user.

I have the following (which didn't work, I get a warning about "unknown protocol: c" (which I don't even know what that means)):

```
BG = //The CSS String
    "-fx-background-position : 50% 50%;\n" +
    "-fx-background-repeat : no-repeat;\n" +
    "-fx-background-size : contain;\n" +
    "-fx-background-image : url(\"" + GS.bgImage.getAbsolutePath() + "\");\n";

BG += "-fx-border-width : " + GS.borderWidth + ";\n" //For adding the Border
    + "-fx-border-color : " + GS.borderColor.toString();

this.setStyle(BG);
```

`GS` is a class I constructed from which the control reads the information to know what to make itself look like. `GS.bgImage` is the background image control is trying to use as it's background. So... what am I doing wrong here? Should i not be using `.getAbsolutePath()`? Is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so it turns out trying to do it with File.getPath() or File.getAbsolutePath() was the issue. Turns out to make it work in code you need to use File.toURI().toURL().

So the proper method would be:

```
BG = //The CSS String, you need to wrap with a Try/Catch to capture a MalformedURLException, but I'm too lazy to do that here...
    "-fx-background-position : 50% 50%;\n" +
    "-fx-background-repeat : no-repeat;\n" +
    "-fx-background-size : contain;\n" +
    "-fx-background-image : url(\"" + GS.bgImage.toURI().toURL + "\");\n";

BG += "-fx-border-width : " + GS.borderWidth + ";\n" //For adding the Border
    + "-fx-border-color : " + GS.borderColor.toString();
```